# What damage is doubled when using decisive strike?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, damage

Regarding *decisive strike* from PHBII:

> If the attack hits, it deals double damage (as does any other attack you make before the start of your next turn).

Does this follow the rules of critical strikes where additional damage dice are not doubled (e.g. if a wizard cast sonic weapon on a bow, critical strikes won't double sonic weapon damage), or does it double all damage dealt? It seems like decisive strike does not have the exception outlined for critical hits on p.140 in the PHB, so it would appear to double everything. I am unsure, though.

Comment: Please don't add answer material to questions — it makes them no longer actually questions for others to answer. I've undone that edit, and added that information to the answer instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The “rules of critical strikes” as you (and, frankly, almost everyone else) think of them, are *actually* the [rules for multiplying damage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#multiplyingDamage) (and critical strikes are by far the most common way of doing that). Those rules are, for the record (in the PHB on page 134),

> #### Multiplying Damage
>
> Sometimes you multiply damage by some factor, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage (with all modifiers) multiple times and total the results. Note: When you multiply damage more than once, each multiplier works off the original, unmultiplied damage.
>
> *Exception:* Extra damage dice over and above a weapon’s normal damage are never multiplied.

So this applies to decisive strike exactly the same as it does to critical strikes, and various charge multipliers (mounted lance charges, Spirited Charge, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer & source link. The reason I think of them that way ("rules of critical strikes") is because the player's handbook sitting in front of me labels it exactly as such. Sidebar on the bottom of page 140. The relevant quote: "Exception: Extra damage over and above a weapon’s normal damage, such as that dealt by a sneak attack or the special ability of a flaming sword, is not multiplied when you score a critical hit. "